# Why sort f >f will delete everything?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I want to sort a file called `f` can then store file sorted answer back to f:

```
sort f >f
```

But this command ends up with an empty file `f`, why? and how can I achieve my goal using **one command**, instead of doing this:

```
sort f >1
mv 1 f
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shell creates the output file *before* it invokes the `sort` command. (It has to; otherwise it wouldn't be able to redirect the `sort` commands stdout.) So by the time the `sort` command starts running with `f` as an argument, `f` is an empty file.

You can avoid this by using the `-o` option:

```
sort -o f f
```

which causes the `sort` program itself to create the output file `f` before it starts reading the input file `f`. And because of the way file creation works on Unix-like systems, the input `f` and the output `f` are actually two distinct files.

As the POSIX specification for `sort` says:

> -o *output*
>   Specify the name of an output file to be used instead of the standard output. This file can be the same as one of the input
>   files.

Answer (score 5):

Because `>` creates a new file by truncating it. And it is done first by the shell before the `sort f` command runs.

Answer (score 2):

Because the shell has to set up the redirection (by calling `dup2` and creating a new file) before running `sort`

You could define some function

```
 autosort() {
    mv $1 "$1.tmp$$"
    sort "$1.tmp$$" > $1
 }
```

then use `autosort f`